# Get variable name from within object instance

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to access the var name of this class instance from inside a method..  Can I set the actual variable name as a string on the constructor or something?

```
var myClass = function(filePath){
    this.run = function(){
        //  I want to access the string "x"
        console.log( this.variableName ); // ????

    };
};

var x = new myClass("./sayHi.js");
```

Comment: Not possible, why would you even want that? You can access your instance using the `this` keyword. And you should define your methods on the prototype of the constructor not inside it.

Comment: I don' quite understand what you want to do.

Comment: from what I gather, the intent is for x.run() to print out "x".  I do not think this is possible and agree with @LJ_1102, I am not sure why you would want to do this.

Answer (score -1):

**Pass the variable name as a parameter when you construct it**

```
var myClass = function(assigned_name,filePath){

    this.variableName = assigned_name

    this.run = function(){
        console.log( this.variableName );
    }
}

var x = new myClass('x','./sayHi.js');

x.run()
```

**Output:**

```
'x'
```

**Useful for:**

While many people say this is pointless, I have run into a situation where I need it.  And a side-note, many jQuery operations rely on the principle of knowing what its own variable name is.  It is always '`$`'.  And people refer to '`$`' from inside a jQuery method when assigning anonymous functions to onclick events without realizing that it is exactly what your question is asking for.

You will need this if your `myClass()` object dynamically assigns event handlers that call-back to your specific class instance, as these calls are often reliant on information saved in your specific class variable.  Since your `myClass()` function isn't as wide-spread as jQuery, you can't count on it always being assigned to the same variable, like '`$`'.

Passing its own assigned variable name to itself when it is constructed is the best way I've found to let my class instance know what its global reference is.

Comment: jQuery is a factory function not an instance, from within jQuery `$` is scoped so you can name jQuery what ever you want, there is a `noConflict` mode that leaves `$` unassigned. There is absolutely no good reason for knowing the instances variable name from within the instance as this is a clear violation of clean programming principles, its not within the responsibility of the instance to know what the outer code is doing. What if i push the instance into an array, or dont even assign it to a variable?

Comment: Thank you but, I am really trying to avoid passing constructor an object {path:"myWebWorker.js", varInstanceName : "newWorker"}

Comment: any help would be useful, with this, moldable language
console.log = function(msg){  alert(msg); };